# How to get only a particular field from set of objects in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

I have a model file as

```
public class EmployeeData extends AbstractModel implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private int version;
    private String empName;
    private Date createDate;
    private Set<Address> address ;

    //getter and setters

}
```

and the mapping for the set goes like

```
<set name="address" table="User_address" lazy="true">
    <key column="EMPLOYEEDATA_ID" />
    <many-to-many class="Address" column="address_id" />
</set>
```

now this address object is very heavy having around 25-30 fields. So I want that when this `EmployeeData` object is picked then only one field from this address object should come from the set so that the query also works faster. It is taking 2-3 minutes to fetch just 7-8 records.

Comment: I know there is way of using sql query in hibernate and that will use joins to the tables and get the usernames. But apart from that any way in hibernate ?

Comment: as far as i believe, there is no way to get particular columns data from the Set data (which are mapped as Many to One mapping), unless you go by using HQL which you specified

Comment: (Aside, since this is an old question: there is no need to add "please help me!!!!" to your questions. Readers know you need help, and for native English speakers this phrase is at least unnecessary, if not also begging and pleading. Keep your questions succinct if you can, and concentrate on the technical detail as much as possible. Thanks!)